# Java number of threads in parallel streams in Kubernetes

Tags: java, multithreading, kubernetes

I have a Java service deployed in Kubernetes, and it uses parallel streams for concurrent processing. I [read](https://java2blog.com/java-8-parallel-stream/#:%7E:text=Parallel%20Stream%20takes%20the%20benefits%20of%20all%20available%20CPU%20cores%20and%20processes%20the%20tasks%20in%20parallel.%20If%20number%20of%20tasks%20exceeds%20the%20number%20of%20cores%2C%20then%20remaining%20tasks%20wait%20for%20currently%20running%20task%20to%20complete.) that the number of threads that spawed is being determined by the number of cores that the machine has in the parallel streams. If my Kubernetes configuration for cpu is 0.8m limit (0.8 milliCPU), how many threads will be spawed? I'm trying to understand the behavior of parallel streams in terms of thread usage in this constrained environment.

Based on the allocated CPU resources, I suspect that the number of threads spawned by the parallel streams (ForkJoinPool) will be 0-1. However, I'm unsure about the exact number of threads being utilized in this scenario. Is by any chance considers the node cores?

Can someone explain how many threads will be spawned by parallel streams in Java when the service is deployed in Kubernetes with e.g. 0.8m CPU? Additionally, any insights into the factors that may influence the number of threads in such an environment would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The number of threads in the common pool is equal to the number of available processors (cores) returned by `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors().`
Remember when your service runs in a Kubernetes pod, the JVM is unaware of the CPU limits you've set in the pod spec. The JVM sees the number of cores available on the underlying node that it's running on and not the limit set in the pod spec. This will result in  `availableProcessors()` returning the number of cores available on the node.

Example,  if you set a CPU limit for the pod that's less than 1 CPU, e.g 0.8m CPU (which is equivalent to 0.0008 of a CPU core, since the m stands for milliCPU units), your service may end up creating more threads than there are CPUs available within the limit you've set. It's also important to note that while setting a CPU limit, 0.8m is 0.0008 of a CPU core, not 0.8 of a CPU core.

Attached are resource materials related to this that are helpful for your use case. [1] [2]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/

[2] https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/04/04/openjdk-and-containers

Comment: As of JDK 17, the JVM is now aware of container limits. See:
https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/04/19/java-17-whats-new-openjdks-container-awareness